# Return statement returns half-right. (half-solved, possibly a bug?)

Tags: java, return

```
//finds the exactNode, where node.data = target
private Node findExact(int target) {
    Node init = head;

    if(init == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int index = 0;
    int size = getSize();
    while((index < size) && (init.data != target)) {
        init = init.next;
        index++;

        //returns null if called from main method. However does not
        //return null out of main method (within other methods in the same class)
        if ((index == size - 1) && (init.data != target)) { 
            return null;
        }
    }

    //this if block is needed somehow, to actually return null if findExact() is
    //used in other methods in the same class.
    if(init == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return init;
}
```

About an hour ago:
Without the last if-block, calling the method from the main method  returns null, however it returns the address of last init in the while loop.

Now:
It works fine without the last if-block, I have 0 clue why.
Can someone elaborate on this? Whether if I was trying to solve something
that never happened, or if it's a bug?
If it is a bug, then how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to myself, but a simpler implementation:

```
private Node findExact(int target) {
    Node init = head;
    int index = 0;
    int size = this.getSize();

    while(index < size) {
        if(init.data == target)
            return init;
        init = init.next;
        index++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This mightn't be a proper answer, but I'm afraid it'll get both too long for a comment and as good as you can get. The problem is that the code is pretty messy.

- You seem to be implementing a `LinkedList`, why?
- What do you need `size` for, when the list is `null`-terminated anyway?
- The condition in `if (init == null) {return null;} return init;` is provably useless, why do you even think about it?

Consider something like

```
private Node findExact(int target) {
    for (Node init = head; init != null; init = init.next) {
        if (init.data == target) {
            return init;
        }
        if (init.isTail()) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Just go through the list, if you find the right node, then return it, otherwise return null. That's all. Don't add bugs to fix bugs added earlier.

In case you don't like the for loop, try this

```
private Node findExact(int target) {
    Node init = head;
    while (init != null && init.data != target) {
        init = init.next;
        if (init == head) { // back to head again
            return null;
        }
    }
    return init;
}
```

Comment: It's a circular doubly linked list, so I figured that it would need size to know when init == tail. I do have a separate method boolean isTail() however..

Comment: @User.Who You still need no `size`, though using it might make sense. See my update. Consider the possibility of a bug in the list creation/update... your list may look different and this may cause problems. Add a `selftest()` method checking some invariants...